# Incomplete match with AND patterns

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, active-pattern

I've defined an expression tree structure in F# as follows:

```
type Num = int
type Name = string
type Expr = 
    | Con of Num
    | Var of Name
    | Add of Expr * Expr
    | Sub of Expr * Expr
    | Mult of Expr * Expr
    | Div of Expr * Expr
    | Pow of Expr * Expr
    | Neg of Expr
```

I wanted to be able to pretty-print the expression tree so I did the following:

```
let (|Unary|Binary|Terminal|) expr = 
    match expr with
    | Add(x, y) -> Binary(x, y)
    | Sub(x, y) -> Binary(x, y)
    | Mult(x, y) -> Binary(x, y)
    | Div(x, y) -> Binary(x, y)
    | Pow(x, y) -> Binary(x, y)
    | Neg(x) -> Unary(x)
    | Con(x) -> Terminal(box x)
    | Var(x) -> Terminal(box x)

let operator expr = 
    match expr with
    | Add(_) -> "+"
    | Sub(_) | Neg(_) -> "-"
    | Mult(_) -> "*"
    | Div(_) -> "/"
    | Pow(_) -> "**"
    | _ -> failwith "There is no operator for the given expression."

let rec format expr =
    match expr with
    | Unary(x) -> sprintf "%s(%s)" (operator expr) (format x)
    | Binary(x, y) -> sprintf "(%s %s %s)" (format x) (operator expr) (format y)
    | Terminal(x) -> string x
```

However, I don't really like the `failwith` approach for the `operator` function since it's not compile-time safe. So I rewrote it as an active pattern:

```
let (|Operator|_|) expr =
    match expr with
    | Add(_) -> Some "+"
    | Sub(_) | Neg(_) -> Some "-"
    | Mult(_) -> Some "*"
    | Div(_) -> Some "/"
    | Pow(_) -> Some "**"
    | _ -> None
```

Now I can rewrite my `format` function beautifully as follows:

```
let rec format expr =
    match expr with
    | Unary(x) & Operator(op) -> sprintf "%s(%s)" op (format x)
    | Binary(x, y) & Operator(op) -> sprintf "(%s %s %s)" (format x) op (format y)
    | Terminal(x) -> string x
```

I assumed, since F# is magic, that this would just work. Unfortunately, the compiler then warns me about incomplete pattern matches, because it can't see that anything that matches `Unary(x)` will also match `Operator(op)` and anything that matches `Binary(x, y)` will also match `Operator(op)`. And I consider warnings like that to be as bad as compiler errors.

So my questions are: Is there a specific reason why this doesn't work (like have I left some magical annotation off somewhere or is there something that I'm just not seeing)? Is there a simple workaround I could use to get the type of safety I want? And is there an inherent problem with this type of compile-time checking, or is it something that F# might add in some future release?

Comment: I think that this sort of problem is unlikely to be fixed.  In the general case it will require solving the halting problem.  I think the most elegant solution would be to add an extra layer of patterns so that you returned `Unary(x,op)`.

Comment: I actually considered doing that, but I wanted to keep my pattern specific to one use case (classifying the arity of the expression and extracting its arguments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you code the destinction between ground terms and complex terms into the type system, you can avoid the runtime check and make them be complete pattern matches.

```
type Num = int
type Name = string

type GroundTerm = 
    | Con of Num
    | Var of Name
type ComplexTerm =
    | Add of Term * Term
    | Sub of Term * Term
    | Mult of Term * Term
    | Div of Term * Term
    | Pow of Term * Term
    | Neg of Term
and Term =
    | GroundTerm of GroundTerm
    | ComplexTerm of ComplexTerm


let (|Operator|) ct =
    match ct with
    | Add(_) -> "+"
    | Sub(_) | Neg(_) -> "-"
    | Mult(_) -> "*"
    | Div(_) -> "/"
    | Pow(_) -> "**"

let (|Unary|Binary|) ct = 
    match ct with
    | Add(x, y) -> Binary(x, y)
    | Sub(x, y) -> Binary(x, y)
    | Mult(x, y) -> Binary(x, y)
    | Div(x, y) -> Binary(x, y)
    | Pow(x, y) -> Binary(x, y)
    | Neg(x) -> Unary(x)

let (|Terminal|) gt =
    match gt with
    | Con x -> Terminal(string x)
    | Var x -> Terminal(string x)

let rec format expr =
    match expr with
    | ComplexTerm ct ->
        match ct with
        | Unary(x) & Operator(op) -> sprintf "%s(%s)" op (format x)
        | Binary(x, y) & Operator(op) -> sprintf "(%s %s %s)" (format x) op (format y)
    | GroundTerm gt ->
        match gt with
        | Terminal(x) -> x
```

also, imo, you should avoid boxing if you want to be type-safe. If you really want both cases, make two pattern. Or, as done here, just make a projection to the type you need later on. This way you avoid the boxing and instead you return what you need for printing.

Comment: Interesting idea. I don't know if I will use this, since I want to keep my union simple, but this is probably the best solution if I really want type safety.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can make `operator` a normal function rather than an active pattern. Because  operator is just a function which gives you an operator string for an `expr`, where as `unary`, `binary` and `terminal` are expression types and hence it make sense to pattern match on them.

```
let operator expr =
    match expr with
    | Add(_) -> "+"
    | Sub(_) | Neg(_) -> "-"
    | Mult(_) -> "*"
    | Div(_) -> "/"
    | Pow(_) -> "**"
    | Var(_) | Con(_) -> ""


let rec format expr =
    match expr with
    | Unary(x) -> sprintf "%s(%s)" (operator expr) (format x)
    | Binary(x, y) -> sprintf "(%s %s %s)" (format x) (operator expr) (format y)
    | Terminal(x) -> string x
```

Comment: In this case you do give up some of the compile-time safety, though. As soon as you extend the `Expr` by another case, your `operator` will just simply return the (potentially wrong) result `""` as opposed to giving you a compiler warning, that you need to extend your function for the new case.

Comment: I guess that can be solved by not using `_` case and specifying each case (see my updated answer)

Comment: Having it as a function is how I started out. But that still isn't compile-time safe, because it's just returning an empty string where it doesn't make any sense to call the function. I would almost rather have it throw an exception, like I originally had, so at least then I know it was called erroneously. But at least with your way (listing each type explicitly), I would get a warning to update the function whenever I updated my union.

Answer (score 2):

I find the best solution is to restructure your original type defintion:

```
type UnOp = Neg
type BinOp = Add | Sub | Mul | Div | Pow
type Expr =
  | Int of int
  | UnOp of UnOp * Expr
  | BinOp of BinOp * Expr * Expr
```

All sorts of functions can then be written over the `UnOp` and `BinOp` types including selecting operators. You may even want to split `BinOp` into arithmetic and comparison operators in the future.

For example, I used this approach in the (non-free) article ["Language-oriented programming: The Term-level Interpreter
"](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.co.uk/2008/01/language-oriented-programming-term.html) (2008) in the [F# Journal](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/products/fsharp_journal/).